# Can't bootstrap with Juju due to " error back from server: 401 UNAUTHORIZED"

Tags: ssh, vpn, juju, maas

I have this little MAAS with only one node ready to deploy (Ubuntu 12.04 Precise pangolin).

I was trying to set up the [Juju](https://jaas.ai/) environment, but I continuously get this error:

```
$ juju bootstrap 
Bootstrap failed, destroying environment 
ERROR Bootstrap failed, and the environment could not be destroyed:
 gomaasapi: got error back from server: 401 UNAUTHORIZED (Invalid consumer.) 
ERROR could not access file 'a576cc0e-bf67-4b7c-8c22-eacb51826eaf-provider- state':
 gomaasapi: got error back from server: 401 UNAUTHORIZED (Invalid consumer.)
```

I tried changing the API key to a fresh one from MAAS, but that didn't help -- actually I got the same error code.

I am communicating through an SSH connection over a VPN from Windows 7 with PuTTY.  The server and my host are authenticated through an RSA key. I tried to change the enviroment.yaml, but to my eyes it all seems to be correct.

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

401 is essentially letting you know you're credentials are not clearing at the MAAS level. Make sure your SSH key from both machines are enlisted in MAAS, and that you removed `~/.juju/environments/maas.jenv` from your machine as it caches information.